# Magento - Get product items attribute in view.phtml

Tags: magento, attributes, magento-1.7

I am trying to load a custom category in the *catalog/category/view.phtml* to archive this I use:

```
<?php
$_category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load(47);
$_productCollection = $_category->getProductCollection();
if($_productCollection->count()) {
    foreach( $_productCollection as $_product ):
        echo $_product->getProductUrl();
        echo $this->getPriceHtml($_product, true);
        echo $this->htmlEscape($_product->getName());
    endforeach;
}
?>
```

I can load the URL for example, now I want to load a custom attribute for example color:

```
$_product->getResource()->getAttribute('color')->getFrontend()->getValue($_product)
```

This code does not work, I am 100% sure the color attribute is set to show in the category listing and also that the items in this category have this fields fill. I know this because this code works on *list.html*.

What I am doing wrong? I am working with 1.7.0.2.

The expected result is to show all COLOR attibutes from a custom cateogory in

> catalog/category/view.phtml

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can't believe I just found the answer. Because we are not in a regular category listing we need to add the custom attributes to the collection.

**Here is the code:**

```
$_productCollection = $_category->getProductCollection()
->addAttributeToSelect('color');
```

Comment: I accidentally downvoted this. If you edit it, I'll gladly retract.

Answer (score 2):

If "color" is in the flat table you should be able to

```
$_product->getColor();
```

If this attribute is not in the collection, you can either add it to the flat table by making the attribute filterable, add it in the PHP collection call

```
$_productCollection = $_category->getProductCollection()
    ->addAttributeToSelect('color');
```

Or load the product model to get all of the attributes

```
$_product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($_product->getId());
echo $_product->getColor();
```

Comment: The problem is that because you are not in the list "yet" Magento does know that this attribute is associated. At least for me it does not work.

Comment: Sorry I don't mean you I mean the 'color' is not in the collection.

Answer (score 1):

1. Make this attribute visible in listing/frontend
2. Run Reindexing
3. `foreach( $_productCollection as $_product ):
       echo $_product->getProductUrl();`

in this code  `var_dump $_product->getData();`  check if this `var_dump` results in that specific attribute value getting displayed.

**Note:**

```
$_product->getResource()->getAttribute('color')->getFrontend()->getValue($_product)
```

is not a very efficient way of calling.